# Calculating Confidence Interval for Estimated Parameters of SEIR model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, optimization, descriptive-statistics, point-estimation

I used a Log-Likelihood Estimation (Poisson) Objective Function to estimate and fit a curve to a data of reported infected cases of COVID-19 using SEIR model in order to estimate its coefficients. How can I calculate the 95% confidence intervals for these estimated coefficients?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Monte Carlo approach to estimate the variation of the parameters. Such method is explained in this blogpost https://blog.ephorie.de/contagiousness-of-covid-19-part-i-improvements-of-mathematical-fitting-guest-post

Also you can estimate the variance of parameters based on the Fisher information matrix which can be approximated with the second-order derivative of an empirical likelihood function (based on your MLE and estimate of deviance).

I am sure that there are several posts about this already on this Q&A site. If you search for ['variance of parameter estimates'](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variance%20of%20parameter%20estimates) or something like that you might find out more.

Comment: Yes! I figured it out using Fisher's Information Matrix. Monte Carlo Approach is good too. Thank You